# "Normalize" hash of Key in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

HashMap keeps its data in buckets as:

```
transient Node<K,V>[] table;
```

To put something in HashMap we need a hash() function which returns hash of Key in range from 0 to table.length(), right?

Suppose, I have:

```
String s = "15315";

// Just pasted internal operation. Is it supposed to calcule hash in table.length range?
int h;
int hmhc = (h = s.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
System.out.println("String native hashCode: "+s.hashCode() + ", HashMap hash: "+hmhc);
```

This returns the following:

> String native hashCode: 46882035, HashMap hash: 46882360

We should have approximately 256 buckets (so hash of Key should be in range from 0 to 256), but internal hash in HashMap gives us 46882360. How to "normalize" this hash to our range? I just can't see it in the source code.

I looked at this jdk ( put() starts from line 610): http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the hash code returned will be taken modulo the number of buckets.

In your case, it will go into bucket `46882360 % 256 = 56`.

Comment: Yeah, how could I forget about it...  But there's no modulo operator in the given JDK. Can you help me to find "normalization" in it? put() starts from line 610

Comment: @GeorgeZorikov Look at how the table is indexed - `(n - 1) & hash`, that selects an index based on the bits in the hash code.

Comment: I figured it out! They use (table.length()-1) & hmhc. As our length is always a power of 2, modulo operator can be replaced with bitwise AND operator. Thank you!